# how do you make NVDA stop announcing "link"

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

Using the NVDA screenreader to read a webpage in Firefox under Windows 10, NVDA is announcing "link" whenever it comes across a linked word or phrase. I can't find a way to turn that feature off. I've turned the "Punctuation/Symbol Level" preference to "none", but it still announces links. Is there a way to stop announcing links?

Comment: Do you ask as a user of the screen reader? Or do you use it for testing, and you want to disable it because it’s annoying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to get this work, even after closing and re-opening NVDA, so perhaps I am misunderstanding this feature. Maybe you will have better luck:

https://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvda/documentation/userGuide.html?#DocumentFormattingSettings

> #### 9.1.12. Document Formatting Settings (NVDA+control+d)
>
> This dialog box is found in the Preferences menu, under "Document Formatting...".
>
> Most of the checkboxes in this dialog are for configuring what type of formatting you wish to have reported as you move the cursor around documents. For example, if you check the report font name checkbox, each time you arrow onto text with a different font, the name of the font will be announced.
>
> […]
>
> - Elements
>
>   - Headings
>   - Links
>   - Lists
>   - Block quotes
>   - Landmarks
>   - Frames
>   - Clickable

Comment: You RULE! That was exactly the right setting. Thank you!